# Mount USB flashdrive on Samsung Galaxy Pocket Neo

Tags: usb, samsung, mount, usb-on-the-go

I have a USB flash drive that has two connections, one USB and one micro USB. I have attached it to may phone but it won't mount. I have tried rooting and using other file browsers but nothing seems to help. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could get the flash drive to mount. I have tried StickMount but that doesn't seem to work.

The flash drive looks something like this:

[image: image of the flash drive]
<sub>(source: [76.my](https://76.my/Malaysia/sandisk-ultra-dual-usb-micro-flash-drive-otg-16gb-32gb-64gb-memory-junelaw-1405-09-junelaw@4.jpg))</sub>

**Edit:** I have tried it in 2 other phones but no luck. I then tried it in my tablet and it worked perfectly. Can anyone explain why it would work in a tablet but not a phone.

Comment: Are you using an OTG cable or just plugging the micro usb flash drive straight into the phone?

Comment: @TimWilkinson I could try using a OTG cable if that helps.

Comment: I cant imagine it would, but thats all i have ever used, also what size flash drive is it, 16, 32 or 64gb?

Comment: Its 16gb, I have tried the cable just now but no look.

Comment: Have you tried using ES File Manager? Have you got a different USB flash drive you could try to see if the issue is with the Phone or Flash drive.

Comment: Does your device support OTG correctly at all? You could check that using an [OTG Helper](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_534).

Comment: Do you have root access. Which android version does your phone has? And Which Phone?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that your phones does not support OTG cables, most android devices (70%) support OTG but some don't. The reason for this, is because your phone hasn't got the right hardware for it I have a tablet that doesnt support it and managed to get it to eventually working **alright** (It doesnt work in other apps, but you can copy the files at a fast speed using some applicatons that are built around this one) by using [USB OTG Helper [root]](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dnet.shajul.usbotg%26hl%3Den&ei=i72qVM_BGoTgaMvmgbAP&usg=AFQjCNEQmzFf3uXlh6DBItn-qTTMC1QUWg&sig2=rUaIZx4HN3Y3uSFUf05zrw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d2s), Please let me know if this works for you
**THIS REQUIRES ROOT ACCESS**
Also you could try charging your phone to 100% and then trying again, If none of this works then it would be most likely because of your phone not supplying enough voltage to the drive, so you may need a external power supply

Comment: I have tried OTG helper but no luck so I have purchased a external power supply but still nothing.

Comment: Then you dont have the right hardware in your phones, and the only way to fix this would be taking the phone apart and putting different hardware in. One last way of doing it would be to connect it to your tablet, share the root usb folder (On tablet) and then open it up on your phone

Comment: Are you sure it is a hardware problem and there is nothing else i can do. Like editing or using a diffrent ROM.

Comment: I am not 100% sure

Comment: It is generally cheaper to use the same hardware across similar models of a phone. What usually is different is the software and in this case, quite possibly your phone's `kernel` does not support `OTG`. Having said that it is usually not easy to find the right kernel sources, compile it, create a new image of your phone and download this new image, whic would let the drive mount correctly...